# Find a sequence $(b_n)_n$ such that $\sum_n b_n = 0$ and $g(t) \equiv \sum_n e^{-2\lambda_n t}a_n^2 + \sum_n e^{-\lambda_n t} a_n b_n + \sum_n b_n^2$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, laplace-transform

Fix a sequence of real numbers $(a_n)_n \in \ell^2$ and a sequence of positive numbers $(\lambda_n)_n \in \ell^2$.

**Question.** What is a crisp characterization of functions $g:[0,\infty) \to [0,\infty)$, is it always possible to construct a sequence of real numbers $(b_n)_n \in \ell^2$ such $\sum_n b_n = 0$ and
$$
g(t) = \sum_n e^{-2\lambda_n t}a_n^2 + \sum_n e^{-\lambda_n t} a_n b_n + \sum_n b_n^2\,\,\forall t \in [0,\infty) ?
$$

Comment: The RHS tends to $\sum_n b_n^2<+\infty$ as $t\to +\infty$. But what if $g(t)\to +\infty$ as $t\to +\infty$?

Comment: Indeed, I forgot to to say that I'm only interested in a large as possible class of functions $g$ for which such a representation is possible. Fixed.

Comment: Just to clarify, you’re asking for which $g$ a valid sequence $b_n$ exists where $a_n$ and $\lambda_n$ are already defined?

Comment: Yes, the $a_n$'s and $\lambda_n$'s are givens.

Comment: Every term $ e^{-2\lambda_n t}a_n^2 +  e^{-\lambda_n t} a_n b_n +  b_n^2$ is nonnegative as it is if the form $\alpha x^2+\beta x+\gamma$ with negative discriminant. Therefore any square summable  sequence $b_n$ with sum equal $0$ is fine.

Comment: I understand your comment. Any square summable sequence $b_n$ is **fine** regarding what ?

Comment: Regarding $g(t)\ge 0$ for any $\lambda_n$ and $a_n.$

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say I **don't** understand your comment, and now that you've clarified it, I don't see how it's useful with regards to the question. Sorry if i missed something.